# Combination Comparison

Tags: algorithm, comparison, combinations

I would like to know others opinion on this problem. I have booking system in mind. Let say that someone pick a date and in server I had list of booked spots.
E.g :

This combination spot is already booked:

[[Room 1, Row 1, spot 1], [Room 2, Row 1, spot 1], [Room 1, Row 2, spot 1]]

User picked: Room 1, Row 2, spot 1.

I have to returned notice that spot is already taken. How should I compare combination of values with other combination of values ?

Thank You

Comment: What is the upper limit of combinations? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, sorry for my late reply. The combination is fixed, so combination always like that. I figured out the easy way is to compare array with array. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to achieve.

- If it should be fast than I would go for a kind of Set based on hash values.
- should the algorithm be short (few code) and time is no matter (maybe because the number of items is always quite low) I would simply go for a linear search
- you could keep the items in a sorted list and than use a binary-search to check if a given item is already in the list
- and many other possibilities.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, and sorry for my late response. I just want to achieve credible data or correct response, so no duplicate booked on the same date. So far, I already run it using array with array comparison, because the structure is fixed. Any other suggestion ? Thanks